# Excel VBA that loops through the folder and move data to the next column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that loop through all the files in a folder m then opens it and looks for the words starting with "Page" in K column and then shift it to the next column, the code I am using is

```
Public Sub  Loop_through_folder_page_no()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\xlsFolder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
 Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

    Dim K As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Set K = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("K:K"))

  For Each r In K
    If Left(r.Text, 4) = "Page" Then
    r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
    r.Clear
    End If
  Next r

ActiveWorkbook.Save


wbk.Close True
Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

this code is giving an error I cant figure it out what's wrong with it.

Comment: What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: I debug it and it is giving error on the line starting with "For Each r In K"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K is a range and r is a range, so I'm not sure you can say "For each range in range." If you're trying to loop through the cells in range K, you can try adding .Cells to the end of the For loop (`For Each r In K.Cells`).

Answer (score 0):

Use a **single line:**

```
Public Sub Loop_through_folder_page_no()
```

There may be other errors.